# 2gis API в iOS приложении

Tags: ios

Хотел уточнить, чтобы использовать карту 2gis, нужно ее выводить в webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, можно использовать MKMapView и добавить тайлы 2gis при помощи https://github.com/2gis/iOS-SDKs-for-tiles

Answer (score 0):

Да, чтобы использовать карту 2gis, нужно ее выводить в webview.